# Using models with sub models in CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, codable

I am trying to implement a cache using `CoreData`.

Up until this point I've been storing models that are simple, however I have a model below that contains data types such as `CodablePartialUser` and `CodableFeedItemType`.

How should these types be modelled in CoreData?

Should I use the `Data` type and store them in a data format?

As `CodableFeedItemType` is an enum, should I store the raw value and convert between formats again?

```swift
struct CodablePartialUser: Equatable, Codable {
  let userID: String
  let firstName: String
  let lastName: String

  init(userID: String, firstName: String, lastName: String) {
    self.userID = userID
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
  }
}

enum CodableFeedItemType: String, Codable {
  case recognition = "RECOGNITION"
  case news = "COMPANY_NEWS"
}

struct CodableFeedItem: Codable {

  let id: String
  let type: CodableFeedItemType
  let createdDate: Date
  let createdBy: CodablePartialUser
  let likesCount: Int
  let commentsCount: Int
  let externalID: String
  let title: String?
  let imageURL: URL?

  init(id: String, type: CodableFeedItemType, createdDate: Date, createdBy: CodablePartialUser, likesCount: Int, commentsCount: Int, externalID: String, title: String?, imageURL: URL?) {
    self.id = id
    self.type = type
    self.createdDate = createdDate
    self.createdBy = createdBy
    self.likesCount = likesCount
    self.commentsCount = commentsCount
    self.externalID = externalID
    self.title = title
    self.imageURL = imageURL

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For the CodablePartialUser you can use relationship by creating a new Entity named as "CodablePartialUser"
- For CodableFeedItemType you can use enum as like

  ```
  enum CodableFeedItemType: String, Codable {
      case recognition = "RECOGNITION"
      case news = "COMPANY_NEWS"
  }

  extension CodableFeedItemEntity {
      var type: CodableFeedItemType {
          get {
              return CodableFeedItemType(rawValue: typeRaw)!
          }
          set {
              typeRaw = newValue.rawValue
          }
      }
  }
  ```